# Multicolumn spacing issue with moderncv

Tags: minipage, moderncv

Just trying to have 2 columns spaced a bit. I use a minipage to do it, and it seems I have some space left. For example, I can add words to my right title, and it's still good with columns ratio 0.55/0.45. But if I use column ratio 0.6/0.4, I got a linebreak is the section header of the right column.

I know it is not clear so here are some screenshots:

1. ratio 0.55/0.45 [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoQRM.jpg)
2. ratio 0.6/0.4 [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwIby.jpg)

and here is the code

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\section{Formation}
\cventry{2002 -- 2008}{Diplôme d'ingénieur en informatique}{}{}{EPITA}{Spécialité Multimédia et Technologies de l'Information}
\cventry{2000 -- 2002}{Baccalauréat Scientifique}{}{}{}{Spécialité Mathématiques}
\end{minipage}
%second column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\section{Langues}
\cvlanguage{Anglais}{Courant}{}
\cvitem{Allemand}{Scolaire}{}
\cvitem{Japonais}{Notions}{}
\end{minipage}
```

Please help me to space out these columns, thanks!

Edit: here is a sample of the page so people can try it!

```
% Template : http://blog.madrzejewski.com/creer-cv-elegant-latex-moderncv/

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.8cm}

\firstname{xxx}
\familyname{XXX}
\title{Ingénieur de développement logiciel senior}
\address{xxx}{XXX}
\email{xxx@gmail.com}
\social[linkedin]{xxx}
\mobile{xxx} 
\extrainfo{xxx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% first column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\section{Formation}
\cventry{2002 -- 2008}{Diplôme d'ingénieur en informatique}{}{}{EPITA}   {Spécialité Multimédia et Technologies de l'Information}
\cventry{2000 -- 2002}{Baccalauréat Scientifique}{}{}{}{Spécialité Mathématiques}
\end{minipage}
%second column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\section{Langues}
\cvlanguage{Anglais}{Courant}{}
\cvitem{Allemand}{Scolaire}{}
\cvitem{Japonais}{Notions}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) would be much better than a thousand screenshots ;-)

Comment: Looking at the code, you have minipages of a combined length of `textwidth`, plus a space and possibly a parindent. That is more than is allowed on one line.

Comment: Thank you @Joannes_B since your comment led me to the answer. I don't understand very well why but with 0.7/0.5 ratio my minipages are displayed perfectly.

Comment: That cannot be the solution.

Comment: I understand it is not technically beautiful but it produced exactly what I wanted : [image](http://i.imgur.com/LOaCWre.png) I'd be glad to get a more correct solution though.

Comment: Without knowing how you generate the pictures you provide, it is impossible to help. For example, when i build a minimal example out of the data you provided, i see something completely different. Get us a compilable example that leads to the output you see. Shouldn't be that hard for one with a *Diplôme d'ingénieur en informatique* ;-)

Comment: Sure, I edited my original post to add a complete page sample where I only left the interesting part! Thanks for help

Comment: `moderncv` is completely incabable of reliable twocolumn setups, everything i can provide is just as hacky as your solution. I'll write up an answer anyway, with some explanations on what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

`moderncv` is not really set up for two-column curriclum vitaes.

A section heading is constructed of 2 boxes and the separator, setting width of the surrounding minipage will lead to breaking the line in the in the sectiontitle. We can avoid that by issuing `\nolinebreak` at the appropriate places in the defintion of section.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates

\firstname{xxx}
\familyname{XXX}
\title{Ingénieur de développement logiciel senior}
\address{xxx}{XXX}
\email{xxx@gmail.com}
\social[linkedin]{xxx}
\mobile{xxx} 
\extrainfo{xxx}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{.15\textwidth}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}\nolinebreak%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}\nolinebreak%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
  \makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% first column
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
    \section{Formation}
    \cventry{2002 -- 2008}{Diplôme d'ingénieur en informatique}{}{}{EPITA} {Spécialité Multimédia et Technologies de l'Information}
    \cventry{2000 -- 2002}{Baccalauréat Scientifique}{}{}{}{Spécialité Mathématiques}
\end{minipage}}\hfill
%second column
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
    \section{Langues}
    \cvlanguage{Anglais}{Courant}{}
    \cvitem{Allemand}{Scolaire}{}
    \cvitem{Japonais}{Notions}{}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\moderncvstyle{banking}     
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\firstname{shay}
\lastname{shay}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \section{Formation}
    \cventry{2002 -- 2008}{Diplôme d'ingénieur en
    informatique}{}{}{EPITA}{Spécialité Multimédia et
    Technologies de l'Information}
    \cventry{2000 -- 2002}{Baccalauréat
    Scientifique}{}{}{}{Spécialité Mathématiques}
\end{minipage}%
%second column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \section{Langues}
    \cvlanguage{Anglais}{Courant}{}
    \cvitem{Allemand}{Scolaire}{}
    \cvitem{Japonais}{Notions}{}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here a minimal example that shows what's going on.

[image: shayModerncvLinebrreak]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \rule{.4\linewidth}{.9\baselineskip}\rule{.6\linewidth}{.9\baselineskip}\par
    \rule{.4\linewidth}{.9\baselineskip} \rule{.6\linewidth}{.9\baselineskip}\par
    \rule{.4\linewidth}{.9\baselineskip}\nolinebreak \rule{.6\linewidth}{.9\baselineskip}\par
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```